# Inheritance with dataclasses for GridLayout of Kivy Python 3

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, kivy, python-dataclasses

I would like to do that:

```py
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from dataclasses import dataclass

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super.(MyGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Pseudo: "))
        self.pseudo = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.pseudo)

class MyApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    MyApp().run()
```

but with dataclasses. I have made several searches but didn't find anything.

Thanks to @JohnAnderson advices, I tried that:

```py
@dataclass
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    pass


@dataclass
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = MyGrid()
        root.cols = 2
        pseudo = TextInput(multiline=False)
        root.add_widget(Label(text="Pseudo: "))
        root.add_widget(pseudo)
        return root

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    MyApp().run()
```

but I get this error:

```
File AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 921, in _run_prepare
     if not self.built:
 AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'built'. Did you mean: 'build'?
```

These *add_widget* methods came from GridLayout of Kivy.

Someone could help to do this with dataclasses? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not use the `@dataclass` decorator on your `App` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do what you want:

```
class MyApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        root = MyGrid()
        
        root.cols = 2
        pseudo = TextInput(multiline=False)

        root.add_widget(Label(text="Pseudo: "))
        root.add_widget(pseudo)
        return root
```

Comment: Thank you, but then, what is in my class MyGrid() ? If I have nothing in it, I get this error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block after class definition on line 9` . And if I put just `cols : int = 2`, then I get `AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'built'. Did you mean: 'build'?` . What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: If you have nothing in your class definition, just put a `pass` there.

Comment: I have already tried that but I still have the error`AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'built'. Did you mean: 'build'?` from the line `MyApp().run()` ... Do you have an idea ?

Comment: OK, if I remove dataclass, it works. But it means that I don't use dataclass, and I still don't know how to use it with my code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

as you can see [in Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.add_widget), `add_widget` adds a new widget as a child of this widget. So as an example, `parent_widget.add_widget(child_widget)` adds the child to the parent's widgets. This is why you need to use `self.add_widget()` if you want to add a child widget to your class (which is a GridLayout).

Comment: It seems that GridLayout().add_widget(Label(text="Pseudo: ")) should works with dataclasses, I mean I don't have errors anymore, but python seems to crash on my laptop...

Comment: The line `GridLayout().add_widget(Label(text="Pseudo: "))` creates a new `GridLayout` instance and adds a `Label` to it. That new `GridLayout` instance is unrelated to your `MyGrid`. You need to use `self.add_widget()`, which means it must be in a method of the `MyGrid` class.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you for your answer. I tried this in the MyGrid class:                 `def addWidgetFromGridLayout(self):`   `self.add_widget(Label(text="Pseudo: "))` `self.add_widget(pseudo)`  and outside the method `addWidgetFromGridLayout()` But I get `TypeError: MyGrid.addWidgetFromGridLayout() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' `. Can you help from this point now ? Thank you in advance.